# Style blockquote with pure css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a blockquote to look like this:

[image: how the blockquoute should look]

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: with whitespaces]
(it is supposed to be without the white spaces at the beginning of the blockquote

**My HTML/CSS**

```
<blockquote><p>Lore ipsum...</p></blockquote>
```

```css
blockquote {
margin: 1em 2em;
border-left: 1px solid #999;    
padding-left: 1em; }

blockquote:before {
content: open-quote;
font-size: 6em;
line-height: 0px;
margin: 0px 5px 0px -40px;
vertical-align: bottom;
position: relative; left: -15px;
}

blockquote p:first-letter {
margin: .2em .3em .1em 0;
font-size: 220%;
 }
/* without unnecessary font type/color attributes*/
```

I'm looking for something like `position: relative; left: -15px;`, but it should work much more reliable than 
this (more reliable means with different window sizes... oh and it should be pure css... ;-))

Do you know a solution problem that does not leave any unnecessary spaces behind?

Comment: You could try with padding-left?

Comment: Could you give me a hint? How can I use padding-left to not have  white-spaces at the beginning of the blockquote?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. If you just want the 2 divs next to eachother you should use `float:left`.

Comment: If you're going to style a blockquote like this, please use a proper set of curly quotes: **“**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a float left and changed the top/left positioning declarations.

```
blockquote:before{
 content: open-quote;
 font-size: 6em;
 line-height: 0px;
 margin: 0px 5px 0px -40px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 top: .4em;
 left: -.15 em;
}
```

Here is the output. I didn't attempt to match your fonts and colors.
[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! -But now (?) the second (and third...) time the blockquote is used the quotation mark is wrong (single instead of double) -> See: http://i.imgur.com/muMr8.png Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

With a `position: relative` on the `blockquote` you can easily position the pseudo element with `position: absolute`. See this jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/VZxhH/1/

```
blockquote {
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin: 1em 2em;
}

blockquote:before {
    content: open-quote;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 6em;
    left: -38px;
    top: -23px;
}
```

Comment: To remain consistant with question top and left should be in em not pixels.